# android existing activity read intent of file from OnResume

Tags: android, android-intent

I have associated my app with txt file. 
So user can select a file in File explorer app and select my app to open it.
In OnCreate:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();        
    if (action != null && action.equals(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)) {
        txtFilePath = intent.getData().getPath();
    }
```

However, when user did not close my app, and he goes back to file explorer and open another file, OnCreate is not called. OnResusme is called instead.
I put below code in OnResume:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();        
    if (action != null && action.equals(Intent.MAIN)) {
        txtFilePath = intent.getData().getPath();
    }
```

However, txtFilePath  is null. Why? Thank a lot for help.

Comment: Use the **txtFilePath/intent** variable as Global and use that without reassigning **txtFilePath/intent** in onResume().

Answer (score 0):

Do not create a new object of Intent in onResume() method Instead use the existing one which you have used in onCreate Method.

```
     Intent intent;
```

onCreate:

```
    intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();        
    if (action != null && action.equals(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)) {
        txtFilePath = intent.getData().getPath();
    }
```

OnResume:

```
String action = intent.getAction();        
if (action != null && action.equals(Intent.MAIN)) {
    txtFilePath = intent.getData().getPath();
}
```

Comment: I tried your method. I found that "String action = intent.getAction(); " in OnResume did not get updated. The intent still gets same action "Intent.ACTION_VIEW" and same text file "abc.txt" as it first registeredt in OnCreate.  thanks for further suggestion